# Reporting a program exception/error in an objective C program back to developer

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am porting a C# application to mac osx, 
In the C# version of the program we have a try catch() block which catches any exceptions thrown by the program , which may be nullpointer exceptions or anything we've not caught..

The top level exception handler then asks the user if he likes to report it, when the user says report, 
the exception stack is reported to us. which helps identify bugs.

In my OSX app the backend part of the program in C/C++ with User interface in Objective C

Is there a similar feature in an objective C program ?? if not is there any alternate way to report, exception or bug report from within the program ?

Comment: Checkout plcrashreporter

Answer (score 3):

As far as exceptions go, NSError is actually preferred over exceptions in Objective-C for non-fatal errors. This is described in Apple's [Exception Programming Topics: Introduction to Exception Programming Topics for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html) documentation:

> **Important:** You should reserve the use of exceptions for programming or unexpected runtime errors such as out-of-bounds collection access, attempts to mutate immutable objects, sending an invalid message, and losing the connection to the window server.
>
> ...
>
> Instead of exceptions, error objects ([NSError](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSError)) and the Cocoa error-delivery mechanism are the recommended way to communicate expected errors in Cocoa applications. For further information, see [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806).

[Using NSError to Great Effect](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/04/cocoa-tutorial-using-nserror-to-great-effect/) is a good tutorial on NSError (in addition to the afore-linked error handling documentation).

As far as crash/fatal error reporting goes, see the ["Crash Reporter for Cocoa app" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110986/crash-reporter-for-cocoa-app) for a number of the options.